# Split an exception into it's exception type and message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have program which requires a "check mode" in which all errors are logged but not raised to accommodate this I have built a log_crash function which takes an error type and an error message this all works well but I also have some instances where I need to just wrap everything in a big try/except block and catch any exception thrown. E.g.

```py
try:
    #code block
except Exception as Err:
    log(Err)
```

I'm trying to find how I can split the error back up into the message and error type (the x in the code below):

```py
def split_err(err):
    x


err = Exception("this is an exception")
err_type, message = split_err(err)
```

Thanks

Comment: `err.__class__` is the exception class.  `err.args` is a tuple containing the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
err = Exception("This is Exception")
err_type = err.__class__ # This will return error type
error_message = err.args[0] # this will return error message
```